# pROC default DeLong or bootstrap

Tags: proc-r-package

I'd be grateful for advice on whether the DeLong method or 2000 bootstraps is being used as the default ROC curve method. I've been through the pROC pdf guide and am unsure which is the default method. Different parts of the pdf, particularly in the sections regarding the confidence interval of AUC calculation mention DeLong or 2000 bootstraps being the default.

The code I am using includes the following:

```
#generate ROC and Confidence intervals for this bootstrap/dose bin
roc2<-roc(SYNdata_b$Endpoint1,SYNdata_b[,i+2])
roc2_CI<-ci(roc2)

#Generate Youden and Closest to Left
rocY<-coords(roc2,"b",best.method="youden")
roctl<-coords(roc2,"b",best.method="closest.topleft")
```

Thank you very much for any advice here.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the confidence interval of an AUC, hence you are using the [`ci.auc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/ci.auc) function. The documentation page states:

> Default is to use “delong” method except for comparison of partial AUC
>   and smoothed curves, where bootstrap is used.

You haven't specified any partial AUC specification nor any smoothing option, therefore the DeLong method will be used.

In addition, you can look at the output on the console, which will show the method used, for instance here the DeLong:

```
> data(aSAH)
> rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
> ci(rocobj)
95% CI: 0.6301-0.8326 (DeLong)
```

In case of doubt and if the method matters to you, it is best to specify the method explicitly:

```
> data(aSAH)
> rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
> ci(rocobj, method = "delong")
95% CI: 0.6301-0.8326 (DeLong)
> ci(rocobj, method = "bootstrap", boot.n = 10000)
95% CI: 0.6296-0.8283 (10000 stratified bootstrap replicates)
```